# Proof of the functional equation $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

We know that 
$$\xi(s)=\frac{s(s-1)\pi^{\frac{{-s}}2}}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\zeta(s)$$

I want to prove the functional equation
$$\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$$
I could not find it anywhere. My approach is to show that this equality holds:
$$\frac{s(s-1)\pi^{\frac{{-s}}2}}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\zeta(s)=\frac{(1-s)(-s)\pi^{\frac{{s-1}}2}}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)\zeta(1-s)$$
We can get rid of the polynomials straight away because they are clearly the same:
$$\pi^{\frac{{-s}}2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)\zeta(s)=\pi^{\frac{{s-1}}2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)\zeta(1-s)$$

Now, since $\zeta(s)=2^s\pi^{s-1}\text{sin}\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)$
we have

$$\pi^{\frac{{-s}}2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)2^s\pi^{s-1}\text{sin}\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)=\pi^{\frac{{s-1}}2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)\zeta(1-s)$$
Dividing through $\zeta(1-s)$
$$\pi^{\frac{{s-2}}2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)2^s\text{sin}\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\Gamma(1-s)=\pi^{\frac{{s-1}}2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)$$
Using Euler's reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\texttt{sin}(\pi z)}$ we have$$\pi^{\frac{{s}}2}2^s\frac{\Gamma(1-s)}{\Gamma\left(1-\frac{s}{2}\right)}=\pi^{\frac{{s-1}}2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1-s}{2}\right)$$

At this point I am not sure what to do next. Wolfram seems to agree with me [image]

hence perhaps maybe this is the way forward. Could anyone help me out how to finish this? or maybe give me completely new proof, I do not mind either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind guys, You use the gamma duplication formula

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(z+\frac{1}{2})=2^{1-2z}\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma(2z)$$

and the result follows.

Comment: ...and never trust WA too much...